# PHP - Fastest way to download Table data to a CSV - Large Data

Tags: php, csv

I have a large table with 500,000 records, on clicking of a button the data gets downloaded, but it is very slow especially on a bad internet.

I was thinking of Zipping the file and then save it but again I am sure it will take up extra memory for the whole process.

Is there a better way to optimize this CSV download.

```
<?php
        // mysql database connection details
        $host = "localhost";
        $username = "admin";
        $password = "root";
        $dbname = "db_books";

        // open connection to mysql database
        $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

        // fetch mysql table rows
        $sql = "select * from tbl_books";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

        $fp = fopen('books.csv', 'w');

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }

        fclose($fp);

        //close the db connection
        mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
```

Comment: Don't write to the file 500k times, that's insane, concatenate into a variable, then write it to a file, then compress the data. That's going to be probably about 10x-100x faster. Try the concatenation first, you may not even need the compression.

Comment: First thing I learned in my first programming class, i/o is expensive, and i/o to disk is the most expensive of all. I wish there were something comparable to fputcsv to create a row at a time, but it's a one time programming thing to make the csv rows using fgetcsv so it's not that big of a deal. We do a lot of these big csv writes, but I find the stuff starts creating speed issues at > 100000 iterations, even using concatenation.

Comment: @Lizardx Indeed. I personally would put the number of lines before flushing to disk as a variable to avoid memory issues as well, but this is a very helpful answer.

Comment: The ram issue is another one that's good to note, these big loops generate a lot of ram demands, in fact, just to get 100k or so running requires upping the max php ram to 256 mB or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use MySQL `INTO OUTFILE`. It is much faster than looping through the results of your query. You add this to your select statement and MySQL will take care of creating your file for you.
[See more documentation on the abilities here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

Comment: When I heard about this, I was thrilled until I tested it, turns out you have to have full root on the server because most setups don't give permissions for this, so that's one to test, if it works, it's the best solution by far, but it may not work due to write permission issues.

Comment: Good point @Lizardx.  I'm typically doing things like this on an environment I totally control

Comment: This one is so clean and elegant I'd always test it first on the server to see if it works, if it does, you're done, and the test only takes a few minutes. Best run on the command line so you can see the mysql output. Creating row generators is tedious, but certainly not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the page-load thread to compile the CSV before sending to the user. This is why it seems so slow.

If possible, you might want to simply pre-compile the CSV downloads, before the user gets to that point. That way their browser will simply receive the file, not hang while you generate it. If you're concerned about wasting too much time generating files that users never download, perhaps have a background job that generates files when needed, but only if the user has logged on (or into a certain area of your site) within the last X hours.

Alternatively, maybe you could use jQuery/Ajax to display a pop-up dialog that tells the user to wait while their file is being generated, and then disappears once the download is ready.

Comment: Please explain what does pre-compile means, as @Lizardx  stated shall I concatenate to a variable and then open up the CSV file for writing?

Comment: Lizardx and I provided two very different solutions. @Lizardx gave you a way to optimize your code so it runs faster, while I gave you a general theory on how to remove slow running code from the end user's experience.

Comment: Basically, pre-compile means that you use a background job to generate this CSV file completely, before the user even requests to download. That way, the user experience is much faster; Only your background thread will notice it is slow (and who cares about a stupid background thread's feelings? not me ...).

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding it, the I/O issue isn't changed, you're still writing to disk 500k times before the thing is available, which I would consider as always bad practice. The end user still has to wait for it to run, which in my experience can be VERY slow for such massive loops.

Comment: Well but using this method, the CSV is already generated before the end user downloads, so they won't have to wait. It's the background thread that ends up being horribly slow. @user580950 should do both our answers, but can probably get away with only using yours.

Edit for clarification: When I say background thread, I mean a cron job should be generating the CSV ... not anything triggered by download request.